# Why authenticated role is not automatically set after registration in Yii (User+Right extension)

Tags: php, database, yii-extensions, rights

I am using Yii user and rights extension, I want to give `Authenticated` role to a user, who gets registered successfully. But it is not working.
Given below is my registration controller code

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public $defaultAction = 'registration';

```
/**
 * Declares class-based actions.
 */
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),
    );
}
/**
 * Registration user
 */
public function actionRegistration() {
        $model = new RegistrationForm;
        $profile=new Profile;
        $profile->regMode = true;

        // ajax validator
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='registration-form')
        {
            echo UActiveForm::validate(array($model,$profile));
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        if (Yii::app()->user->id) {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->profileUrl);
        } else {
                                    if(isset($_POST['RegistrationForm'])) {

                $rnd = rand(0, 9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999

                $model->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];

                $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($profile, 'picture');

                $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
                $profile->picture = $fileName;

              if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
        {
            //$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/img".$filename);
            $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
            $image = Yii::app()->image->load(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
           $image->resize(70, 70);
            $image->save(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
            }
              $profile->attributes=((isset($_POST['Profile'])?$_POST['Profile']:array()));

                if($model->validate()&&$profile->validate())
                {

                    $soucePassword = $model->password;
                    $model->activkey=UserModule::encrypting(microtime().$model->password);
                    $model->password=UserModule::encrypting($model->password);
                    $model->verifyPassword=UserModule::encrypting($model->verifyPassword);
                    $model->superuser=0;
                    $model->status=((Yii::app()->controller->module->activeAfterRegister)?User::STATUS_ACTIVE:User::STATUS_NOACTIVE);

                    if ($model->save()) {

                        $profile->user_id=$model->id;
                                                    $profile->picture = $fileName;
                        $profile->insert();
                        if (Yii::app()->controller->module->sendActivationMail) {
                            $activation_url = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('/user/activation/activation',array("activkey" => $model->activkey, "email" => $model->email));
                // here
                                                UserModule::sendMail($model->email,UserModule::t("You registered from {site_name}",array('{site_name}'=>Yii::app()->name)),UserModule::t("Please activate you account go to {activation_url}",array('{activation_url}'=>$activation_url)));
                        }

                        if ((Yii::app()->controller->module->loginNotActiv||(Yii::app()->controller->module->activeAfterRegister&&Yii::app()->controller->module->sendActivationMail==false))&&Yii::app()->controller->module->autoLogin) {
                                $identity=new UserIdentity($model->username,$soucePassword);
                                $identity->authenticate();
                                Yii::app()->user->login($identity,0);
                                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
                        } else {
                            if (!Yii::app()->controller->module->activeAfterRegister&&!Yii::app()->controller->module->sendActivationMail) {
                                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('registration',UserModule::t("Thank you for your registration. Contact Admin to activate your account."));
                            } elseif(Yii::app()->controller->module->activeAfterRegister&&Yii::app()->controller->module->sendActivationMail==false) {
                                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('registration',UserModule::t("Thank you for your registration. Please {{login}}.",array('{{login}}'=>CHtml::link(UserModule::t('Login'),Yii::app()->controller->module->loginUrl))));
                            } elseif(Yii::app()->controller->module->loginNotActiv) {
                                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('registration',UserModule::t("Thank you for your registration. Please check your email or login."));
                            } else {
                                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('registration',UserModule::t("Thank you for your registration. Please check your email."));
                            }
                            $this->refresh();
                        }
                    }
                } else $profile->validate();
            }
            $this->render('/user/registration',array('model'=>$model,'profile'=>$profile));
        }
}
```

}

My main.config

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'theme' => 'bootstrap',
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'My Web Application',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload' => array('log'),
    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => 'ext.bootstrap'),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.*',
        'bootstrap.widgets.*',
        'application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.modules.user.components.*',
        'application.modules.rights.*',
        'application.modules.rights.components.*',
         'ext.select2.Select2',
        'application.extensions.*',
        'application.helpers.*',


    //adding these lines to for yii user nd rights
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii' => array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => 'centangle',
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii',),
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', '::1'),
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'tableUsers' => 'user',
            'tableProfiles' => 'profiles',
            'tableProfileFields' => 'profiles_fields',

        ),
        'rights' => array(
            'install' => false,
            'superuserName' => 'Admin', // Name of the role with super user privileges. 
            'authenticatedName' => 'Authenticated', // Name of the authenticated user role. 
            'userIdColumn' => 'id', // Name of the user id column in the database. 
            'userNameColumn' => 'username', // Name of the user name column in the database. 
            //'enableBizRule'=>true,  // Whether to enable authorization item business rules. 
            //'enableBizRuleData'=>true,   // Whether to enable data for business rules. 
            //'displayDescription'=>true,  // Whether to use item description instead of name. 
            'flashSuccessKey' => 'RightsSuccess', // Key to use for setting success flash messages. 
            'flashErrorKey' => 'RightsError', // Key to use for setting error flash messages. 
            //  'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested. 
            'layout' => 'rights.views.layouts.main', // Layout to use for displaying Rights. 
            'appLayout' => 'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout. 
            'cssFile' => 'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights. 
            'install' => false, // Whether to enable installer. 
            'debug' => false,
        ),

    'notifyii', 

    ),
    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'image'=>array(
          'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
            // GD or ImageMagick
            'driver'=>'GD',
            // ImageMagick setup path
            'params'=>array('directory'=>'/opt/local/bin'),
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'class' => 'RWebUser',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
        ),
        'authManager' => array(
            'class' => 'RDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
            'defaultRoles' => array('Authenticated', 'Guest'),
            'itemTable' => 'authitem',
            'itemChildTable' => 'authitemchild',
            'assignmentTable' => 'authassignment',
            'rightsTable' => 'rights',
        ),
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.BsApi',),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' =>array(


             // REST patterns  
            //Packages
            array('packages/list', 'pattern'=>'packages/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('packages/view', 'pattern'=>'packages/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('packages/update', 'pattern'=>'packages/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('packages/delete', 'pattern'=>'packages/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('packages/create', 'pattern'=>'packages/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //Businesses   
            array('businesses/list', 'pattern'=>'businesses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('businesses/view', 'pattern'=>'businesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('businesses/update', 'pattern'=>'businesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('businesses/delete', 'pattern'=>'businesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('businesses/create', 'pattern'=>'businesses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //Addresses   
            array('addresses/list', 'pattern'=>'addresses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('addresses/view', 'pattern'=>'addresses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('addresses/update', 'pattern'=>'addresses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('addresses/delete', 'pattern'=>'addresses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('addresses/create', 'pattern'=>'addresses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //Categories  
            array('categories/list', 'pattern'=>'categories/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('categories/view', 'pattern'=>'categories/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('categories/update', 'pattern'=>'categories/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('categories/delete', 'pattern'=>'categories/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('categories/create', 'pattern'=>'categories/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //ReviewBusinesses  
            array('reviewbusinesses/list', 'pattern'=>'reviewbusinesses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('reviewbusinesses/view', 'pattern'=>'reviewbusinesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('reviewbusinesses/businesspage', 'pattern'=>'businesspage/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('reviewbusinesses/update', 'pattern'=>'reviewbusinesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('reviewbusinesses/delete', 'pattern'=>'reviewbusinesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('reviewbusinesses/create', 'pattern'=>'reviewbusinesses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),    

            //SubCategories 
            array('subcategories/list', 'pattern'=>'subcategories/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('subcategories/view', 'pattern'=>'subcategories/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('subcategories/update', 'pattern'=>'subcategories/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('subcategories/delete', 'pattern'=>'subcategories/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('subcategories/create', 'pattern'=>'subcategories/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),    

            //SubCategoryBusinesses
            array('subcategorybusinesses/list', 'pattern'=>'subcategorybusinesses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('subcategorybusinesses/view', 'pattern'=>'subcategorybusinesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('subcategorybusinesses/businessname', 'pattern'=>'businesslist/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('subcategorybusinesses/update', 'pattern'=>'subcategorybusinesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('subcategorybusinesses/delete', 'pattern'=>'subcategorybusinesses/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('subcategorybusinesses/create', 'pattern'=>'subcategorybusinesses/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),    

            //Users  
            array('users/list', 'pattern'=>'users/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('users/view', 'pattern'=>'users/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('users/update', 'pattern'=>'users/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('users/delete', 'pattern'=>'users/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('users/create', 'pattern'=>'users/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //ItemsReview    
            array('itemsreview/list', 'pattern'=>'itemsreview/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('itemsreview/view', 'pattern'=>'itemsreview/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('itemsreview/update', 'pattern'=>'itemsreview/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('itemsreview/delete', 'pattern'=>'itemsreview/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('itemsreview/create', 'pattern'=>'itemsreview/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //ItemsController
            array('item/list', 'pattern'=>'item/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('item/view', 'pattern'=>'item/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('item/update', 'pattern'=>'item/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('item/delete', 'pattern'=>'item/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('item/create', 'pattern'=>'item/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            //PackagesItems    
            array('packagesitems/list', 'pattern'=>'packagesitems/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('packagesitems/view', 'pattern'=>'packagesitems/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('packagesitems/update', 'pattern'=>'packagesitems/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('packagesitems/delete', 'pattern'=>'packagesitems/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('packagesitems/create', 'pattern'=>'packagesitems/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'), 

            // Other controllers
                'user/registration/<id:\w+>' => 'user/registration',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        /* 'db'=>array(
          'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
          ), */
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=businessadvisor',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
        'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning',
                ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

              array(
              'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
             ),

            ),
        ),
    ),
    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params' => array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add more information?

- Do you have any errors in the application log or somewhere else?
- How is the module configured in the main config?
- What happens if you add the assignment directly in the database?

Update

I think you are on the right track with the authorizer, But before you assign the role to a user you check if the roles are empty. In your config file you assigned default roles to users.

```
'defaultRoles' => array('Authenticated', 'Guest'),
```

The assign() method already checks if a role is assigned to a user see #50 (https://bitbucket.org/crisu83/yii-rights/src/02326a61da3171f5f81f12e49543a7c78a151bf0/components/RDbAuthManager.php?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#RDbAuthManager.php-47)
so it should probably be something like this

```
//...
if ($model->save()) {

    $authorizer = Yii::app()->getModule("rights")->getAuthorizer();
    $authorizer->authManager->assign('Authenticated', $model->id);
//...
```

Comment: 1. My user gets easily registered no error comes.
2. I am attaching my config.main in question you can see it.
3. I can assign the role manually but that's is not what I want.

Comment: Ok, I see you also edited the actionRegistration code. but i think you where on the right track. With the authorizer part after model save. I'll wil update my original answer